# Rsync ignores —chown and —usermap

Tags: debian, rsync

I‘ve tried to copy files from my Mac to a Debian server with rsync. Therefore I installed the current version via Homebrew.

Now the sync is working but my files are owned on the destination by root (the ssh-user) although I use the `—chown=www-data:www-data` or `—usermap=*:www-data` Options. It seems that rsync is ignoring them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The obvious problem that I can see is that the options you've provided are not correct.

Instead of `--chown` your question has `-chown`, containing a single Unicode emdash instead of the expected two standard hyphens.

The same is true of `--usermap` where your question instead shows `—usermap`.

Answer (score 0):

It was a version issue so the version on my mac os doesn't support the `--chown` etc options.